# Flutter / dart. Json.decode nested JSON

Tags: json, flutter, dart, firebase-storage, json-deserialization

I am parsing a JSON from Firebase. When I try to decode it with jsonDecode this exception is thrown:

```
[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: type '_Map<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'
```

To reproduce the error:

```
final Map<String, dynamic>> map = jsonDecode(data);
```

Data is the following String:

```
"{
   "01/10/2023": {
     "enter": "7:0",
     "exit": "17:0",
     "details": "",
     "type": "0005"
   },
   "01/11/2023": {
     "enter": "7:0",
     "exit": "17:0",
     "details": "",
     "type": "0005"
   },
   "01/12/2023": {
     "enter": "7:0",
     "exit": "17:0",
     "details": "",
     "type": "0005"
   }
}"
```

I don't understand why it returns a type that cannot be casted. I don't know the meaning of that underscore.

Comment: Thanks! Now I obtain this: Unhandled Exception: type '_Map<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Map<String, dynamic>>'.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
 final Map<String, dynamic>> map = jsonDecode(data) as Map<String, dynamic>>
```